# In Angular 2 Material, can I consume SCSS Variable like $primary-dark in Components SCSS file while switching themes at runtime?

Tags: angular, sass, material-design, angular-material2

Specifically,

I would like to be able to once implemented..  Have multiple themes and reference `$primary-dark` in any components SCSS file.

Would implement multiple themes from [Theming your Angular Material app](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming)

I am *not* looking for a solution that uses directives.

I am told its not possible.

Comment: What is your definition of "Components SCSS file"? What is you definition of `$primary-dark` (the darker primary color of theme X or the primary color of theme "darker" or ect)?

Comment: The color variable that belongs to all themes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*** UPDATED BECAUSE OF COMMENTS***

If you want to swap them on the fly, you have to still define all of the different themes inside of your `site.scss` file.

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
// Plus imports for other components in your app.

// Include the common styles for Angular Material. We include this here so that you only
// have to load a single css file for Angular Material in your app.
// **Be sure that you only ever include this mixin once!**
@include mat-core();

// Define the default theme (same as the example above).
$candy-app-primary: mat-palette($mat-indigo);
$candy-app-accent:  mat-palette($mat-pink, A200, A100, A400);
$candy-app-theme:   mat-light-theme($candy-app-primary, $candy-app-accent);

// Include the default theme styles.
@include angular-material-theme($candy-app-theme);

// Define an alternate dark theme.
$dark-primary: mat-palette($mat-blue-grey);
$dark-accent:  mat-palette($mat-amber, A200, A100, A400);
$dark-warn:    mat-palette($mat-deep-orange);
$dark-theme:   mat-dark-theme($dark-primary, $dark-accent, $dark-warn);

// Include the alternative theme styles inside of a block with a CSS class. You can make this
// CSS class whatever you want. In this example, any component inside of an element with
// `.unicorn-dark-theme` will be affected by this alternate dark theme instead of the default theme.
.unicorn-dark-theme {
  @include angular-material-theme($dark-theme);
}
```

You would have to add the `.unicorn-dark-theme` class to any component that you want to be themed.

I haven't actually done dynamic themes but I hope that you would be able to put an `ng-class` at a root level and toggle that as needed.

There is a section titled Multiple themes in the theming link that @ttugates originally posted

Also, if you click the little paint bucket icon on the top right of that link, you'll see 4 different theme options.

If you want to play with some demo code, clone the material2 repo locally, install the dependencies and then run `npm run demo-app`.  Great way to play with some live examples.

*** ORIGINAL ANSWER ***

We have a `site.scss` file that declares all of our variables such as

```
$grey-color: mat-color(mat-palette($mat-grey));
```

Then we import the `site.scss` file into any other `.scss` file that we need to use it.

```
@import '../../../styles/site.scss';

.set-for-deletion {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: $grey-color;
}
```

We are using angular-cli for our builds so we include the styles file in the `.angular-cli.json` file like it says in the link you provided.

> If you are using the Angular CLI, support for compiling Sass to css is built-in; you only have to add a new entry to the "styles" list in angular-cli.json pointing to the theme file (e.g., unicorn-app-theme.scss).

Comment: Thanks, I'm running this by my coworker that knows css / angular way better than me to make sure it works with the way we swap SCSS at runtime to chose themes.  Will follow up with question or mark as answer when I get feedback.

Comment: Because we swap the `scss` at runtime, when a user selects a new theme, I am told this approach doesn't work.  I don't know on SO if its appropriate to update my question with the specificity that, we don't import all themes, we swap out the `scss` file at runtime.  Or accept your answer and repost the question.

Comment: You are importing specifically `$grey-color` from `site.scss`, how would you  import say `$primary` from x file that changes at runtime?

Comment: I just updated my answer.  I think that's what you're looking for.

Comment: I agree with this solution but you are still themeing the component inside the `site.scss` file or in a mixin that is imported into the `site.scss`. This is NOT themeing the component from the "Compoent's SCSS file" as stated in the question. (when you define the "Compoent's SCSS file" as the file listing in the component's `styleUrls` metadata )

Comment: You can use the `.unicorn-dark-theme` class code in any of your components `.scss` files.  That example is at a site level.  You can do that at the component level as well.  `.scss` files are compiled into `.css` files.  You can't hot swap values once the `.scss` file is already compiled if that's what you want to do.  And if that is what you want to do, you need to get a stronger grasp on how `.scss` works.

Comment: Yes, you can use the `.unicorn-dark-theme` class code in your component's `.scss` if you import `site.scss` but this is not scale-able as you would have to have a class rule for every theme in every component scss and you would have to `ng-class` every themed component not just the root. With Angular CLI  the component level `.scss` files are not complied to `.css` files but `css` strings with added ViewEncapsulation.

Comment: Also if you did that and you left the `@include angular-material-theme($candy-app-theme);` every single component that imported `site.scss` would include all of the material styling in the <style> tag that angular generates  when a component is rendered.

Comment: I'm confused on why using the `.unicorn-dark-theme` class suggestion at the root level node will not work for you.  You can have multiple classes declared and then have a method which returns which class to use in an `ng-class` statement.  Then it trickles down to all of your components and scales.  You'd still be able to use `$primary-dark` as you would normally but the `ng-class` theme would change that value for you.  Seems like that's your goal.

Comment: I agree that the `.unicorn-dark-theme` class suggestion and following the material guide is correct and solves the ultimate goal of themeing components with multiple/dynamic themes. None of that involves using the theme variables in the "compoenet's scss file" (when you define the "compoenet's scss file" as the file listed in the component's styleUrls metadata, not a file named after the component with mixin imported in the to `site.scss` as in the material guide), I don't think that is viable.

Comment: Not viable outside of @VtoCorleone 's suggestion of moving the `.unicorn-dark-theme` class to the component's scss file I should say, with previous stated scalability problem (you'd need a class for every theme in every component)

Comment: I think I see the confusion. I interpreted @ttugates 's `$primary-dark` as the `mat-color($primary, darker);` of theme X. It could also mean `mat-color($primary);` of theme 'dark'.

Comment: [@VtoCorleone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/557360/vtocorleone) and [@William Lohan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6656422/william-lohan), Than you for all the effort and this answer!

Comment: Glad it got resolved.  Sometimes it just takes a bunch of back and forth to iron it out.